# Computed Property is duplicating

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

```
class test {
    
    var _x : [Int]?
    var x : [Int]? {
        get {
            return _x
        }
        set{
            if let value = newValue {
                for each in value {
                    _x!.append(each)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        _x = [Int]()
        x?.append(3)
    }
    
    
}

var classTest = test()
classTest.x?.append(2)
print(classTest.x)
```

I am getting [3,3,2] instead of [3,2] why i don't understand ? The expected behaviour is that we are appending 3 to x in Initializer and then appending another 2.

***EDIT***

Thank you for all the responses though i am still not getting the hang of this behaviour.

So when i do `.append(2)` swift is grabbing the existing value of `_x` that is 3, then appending 2 to it and then setting the `newValue` to [3,2]. I thought `newValue` only means **new Value** that is the value that was just assigned to the computed property.

Comment: Well, have you checked what `newValue` is in the `set {}` after you append something?

Comment: Why not `set { _x = newValue }`?

Comment: @Roope Yes newValue has the previous value AND the new value that i just appended

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because i want to append and not replace

Comment: try my code and see what happens...

Comment: @dev_ios999 Well then since `newValue` has the previous value and the appended value, and you do a for each loop, surely the expected outcome is that everything gets appended again? If you only want to append the latest value, then don't do a for each loop but only pick the last one? (Or better yet just replace the whole thing like suggested.)

Comment: @Roope Yes but the question is why is `newValue` also getting the existing value(3). Shouldn't it be only getting the new Value like (2) and not existing values

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes it works though i am still not sure how or why. `.append(2)` should set newValue to just 2 but it is also gettting the existing value 3 and then appending the 2 to it how ?

Comment: `newValue` is the new *array*, it isn't just the value that was appended. How would it work if a value was removed?

Comment: "why `.append(2)` should set `newValue` to just 2 but it is also gettting the existing value 3". Well, this behaviour makes the most sense. Consider the case where you are removing an element - `remove(at: 0)`. You are setting the array by doing this, so the setter would be called, but what would `newValue` be this time, according to _your_ logic? Clearly, making `newValue` be the entire new array that is set to the property makes more sense.

Comment: The real question is: What on earth are you trying to achieve here? If you write classTest.x = [1,2]; classTest.x=[1,2] you spend 1,2,1,2 to the existing content. Confusing to say the least.

Comment: Very minor and unrelated observation. Type names (e.g. structs, classes, etc.), always capitalize the first letter. So, you probably want `Test` rather than `test` for the class name.

Comment: if you add `didSet` in _x, you will know why it is being set as [3,3,2]

Answer (score 0):

The reason of duplication is you don't clear an internal variable before you traverse and refill with newValue. So, you're just adding existing array to the same existing array with new value. You can just clear _x before the traverse or apply newValue to _x:

```
class test {
    
    var _x : [Int]?
    var x : [Int]? {
        get {
            return _x
        }
        set{
            _x = newValue

            // or

            _x = []
            if let value = newValue {
                for each in value {
                    _x!.append(each)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        _x = [Int]()
        x?.append(3)
    }
    
    
}

var classTest = test()
classTest.x?.append(2)
print(classTest.x)
```

Comment: Yes i got it but why is in response to `.append(2)` `newValue` is already getting the existing value (3) and appending (2) to it. Shouldn't the value `newValue` just be 2 ?

Comment: @dev_ios999 No, it shouldn't. Because newValue in getter already recieve completed value (with added new element). Method `.append()` changes existing array and something like recreate array _x with all elements (including the new one).
It would be equivalent to `_x = _x + [3]`. Have I answered on your question?

Answer (score 0):

`append` does a `get` to receive a copy of the array property and then appends the new value to this copy and then calls `set` with the new array

So the class can be written as

```
class Test {
    private var _x : [Int]?
    var x : [Int]? {
        get {
            return _x
        }
        set {
            _x = newValue
        }
    }

    init() {
        _x = [Int]()
        x?.append(3)
    }
}
```

Consider the following example where I have added `print("Getting")` to the `get` clause

```
var classTest = Test()

classTest.x?.append(2)
print(classTest.x)
classTest.x = [1,4]
print(classTest.x)
classTest.x?.remove(at: 0)
print(classTest.x)
```

> Getting
> Getting
> Optional([3, 2])
> Getting
> Optional([1, 4])
> Getting
> Getting
> Optional([4])

As you can see it is printing "Getting" both for the `print` command but also for the `append` and `remove` command because it gets a copy to modify